# Get elapsed time between break point hits without stopping the program execution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, debug-diagnostic-tool

I am using Visual Studio "Diagnostic Tools" to get a rough timing analysis on my program. As you know, in VS 2015, the elapsed time between the two break point hits are provided. I would like to know if there is any option that I can set so that these analysis would be stored in a file (or displayed) without stopping the program execution?

Thanks!

Comment: I raise ETW-Eventsource Events (1 at start 1 at stop, both have same task and one has Opcode Start and the other the opcode stop. When I log them I see the times and I can calculate the duration: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2012/08/13/windows-high-speed-logging-etw-in-c-net-using-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource.aspx

Comment: Would this work if I am developing in C++ ?

Comment: yes, but ugly to use. Look in the evntrace.h